# Multiple LIKE Operator ORDER BY Strongest

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE (genre LIKE '%romance%'
    OR genre LIKE '%comedy%'
    OR genre LIKE '%horror%')
ORDER BY *the column that has more*
```

OR SOMETHING LIKE THAT

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE
(genre LIKE '%romance%' AND genre LIKE '%comedy%' AND genre LIKE '%horror%')
#If result < 12
(genre LIKE '%romance%' AND genre LIKE '%comedy%') OR (genre LIKE '%romance%' AND genre LIKE '%horror%') OR (genre LIKE '%comedy%' AND genre LIKE '%horror%')
#If result < 12
(genre LIKE '%romance%' OR genre LIKE '%comedy%' OR genre LIKE '%horror%')";
```

I mean if there is a movie has these three genres I want to get it first else I get movie which has romance and comedy or romance and horror or comedy and horror.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A conditional operator returns `1` when it's true, `0` when it's false. So add up the number of matches.

```
ORDER BY (genre LIKE '%romance%')
        + (genre LIKE '%comedy%')
        + (genre LIKE '%horror%') DESC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d2825/2)

It would be better to normalize your tables. Add a table `movie_genre` like

```
CREATE TABLE movie_genre (
    movie_id INT(11) NOT NULL, # foreign key to movie.id
    genre_id INT(11) NOT NULL  # foreign key to genre.id
);
```

Then you would do a query like:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM movie AS m
JOIN movie_genre AS mg ON m.id = mg.movie_id
JOIN genre AS g ON g.id = mg.genre_id
WHERE g.name IN ('comedy', 'romance', 'horror')
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Further, you could multiply each `LIKE` by a constant to, for example, give 'romance' more "weight" than 'horror'.